# Field Order in List of SharePoint 2013 App

Tags: column, 2013, ordering, app

I am building a SharePoint 2013 SharePoint hosted app, provisioning a list using Site Columns, but no defined content type, just using the automatically assigned content type ListFieldContentType.

The problem I am having is that the field order in the edit form is not the same as the order I am configuring in the schema. There does not seem to be a UI for changing the order, or any sequence attributes I can assign in the schema xml.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found a [solution](http://djeeg.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/sharepoint-2013-app-list-edit-form.html), by altering the field GUIDs to be in number order, I can get the fields to provision in the correct order on the edit form.